# How to query a model to fetch data from multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, couchdb, multiple-databases

I have a requirement to fetch the data from Multiple databases for example.

we've 2 databases

1) DB_2016 --> have only 2016/old records(static DB only reads)

2) DB_2017  --> have current/new records (dynamic for reads/writes)

and I have a table/model called Articles.

**scenarios**

a) If I want to grab all 2017/current records of Articles table, I wanted to use DB_2017 database to fetch the records.

b) and If I want to query same Article table to fetch the records from 2016 to 2017. I should go fetch the data from both the DBs i.e DB_2016 and DB_2017.

Is this something possible??

Comment: Check this: http://drnicwilliams.com/2007/04/12/magic-multi-connections-a-facility-in-rails-to-talk-to-more-than-one-database-at-a-time/

Comment: Thank you, but the solution isn't working

Comment: Try out [octopus gem - Database Sharding](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus).

Comment: Thank you, Octopus gem is helpful